# Problema con relaciones entre Transacciones genexus

Tags: postgresql, aplicación-web, genexus, relaciones, transacciones

Mi problema: Tengo dos transacciones (quizás más) que comparten parte de una llave (EmpKey), y que al realizar los diagramas de relación, no me muestra relación alguna entre ellas.

Tablas y relaciones:

[image: Tabla empresa y ubicación, las demás relaciones son para ejemplificar mejor]

La Tabla sucursal, es el ejemplo de como debería estar unida Ubicación a empresa.

Nos dimos cuenta de este problema, al hacer un for each de la tabla ubicación mientras ejecutábamos la aplicación, la navegación muestra un JOIN de ubicación a empresa y de empresa a ubicación.

For each ubicación:

[image: For each ubicación]

Navegación del For each ubicación:

[image: Navegación del For each ubicacion]

Como dato adicional, cuando borro los archivos de compilación y los state's, luego regenero la app completa, esto problema de **Navegación** es corregido, pero **no así las Relaciones de las tablas/transacciones indicadas**, además, despues de unos cuantos cambios y compilaciones, el problema vuelve a ocurrir.

No sé si el problema es de genexus al generar los objetos y relaciones o si es de la bd.

Utilizo:

- Genexus 16 u11
- PostgreSQL

Espero obtener ayuda, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Matias, al parecer, con la info que pasas, si, tendría que haber una relación entre Empresa y Ubicacion en el diagrama de tablas. Podría no haber una relación si hubiera algún subtipo, o que la relación no fuera directa (si no a más de un paso).

Para darte cuenta de esto podrias hacer un diagrama nuevo y agregar todas las tablas (si es que el diagrama en cuestión no las tiene), para ver si aparece alguna tabla entre Empresa y Ubicacion.

De todas formas, si el problema persiste, te recomiendo contactarte directamente con soporte oficial genexus.

Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente utilizo subtipos en Ubicación, pero ¿por que los subtipos "matan" la relación entre esas tablas? yo no lo sé y me gustaría saberlo, ahora si eso tampoco debiera pasar así, claro, contactare al soporte.